# compare and hide all except one of table equal columns

Tags: jquery

I struggle with Jquery and table.

I'm trying to write function that compare columns (not rows) and hides all equal columns but leaves 1.

```
<table id="item-sizes-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        פריט (סיית)
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="43" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="XS (32-34)">XS</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="41" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="S (34-36)">S</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="40" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="M (36-38)">M</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="46" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="L (38-40)">L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="47" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="45" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="39" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="44" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="42" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="XL (40-42)">XL</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        אורך
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="43" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="XS (32-34)"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="41" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="S (34-36)">1S</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="40" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="M (36-38)">1M</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="46" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="L (38-40)">1L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="47" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">1L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="45" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">1L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="39" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">1L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="44" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">1L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="42" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="XL (40-42)">length</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Sleeve
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="43" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="XS (32-34)">2XS</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="41" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="S (34-36)">2S</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="40" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="M (36-38)">2M</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="46" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="L (38-40)">2L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="47" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">2L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="45" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">2L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="39" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">2L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="44" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">2L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="42" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="XL (40-42)">sleeve</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Chest
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="43" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="XS (32-34)">3XS</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="41" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="S (34-36)">3S</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="40" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="M (36-38)">3M</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="46" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="L (38-40)">3L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="47" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">3L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="45" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">3L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="39" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">3L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="44" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)">3L</span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="42" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="XL (40-42)">chest</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Scope
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="43" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="XS (32-34)"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="41" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="S (34-36)"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="40" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="M (36-38)"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="46" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="47" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="45" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="39" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="44" data-duplicate="true">
        <span title="L (38-40)"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-product-id="42" data-duplicate="false">
        <span title="XL (40-42)">scope</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I have this html table where some columns have duplicate columns (they are almost the same only data-product-id attribute is different) basically I need to check if all td elements in the same column has attribute data-duplicate with value true (did that comparison server side in rows)

Comment: Search is based on which column

Comment: data is sorted with php, so I need to compare n with n-1 columns, if all td contents are the same (attributes will differ).

Comment: @Banana I have tried to store column values in arrays and compare them, but that didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there you go:

first we count how many columns we have,

 next we go over every column in a loop and check all its cells

 if all cells are duplicate, we hide the whole column:

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/S3KV5/)**</kbd>

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    //count how many columns we have
    var totalColumns = $("td",$("#item-sizes-table tr").first()).size();
    //go over all the columns
    for(i=1;i<=totalColumns;i++){
        //set a temporary var
        var isDuplicate=true;
        //go over every cell in the column
        $("#item-sizes-table td:nth-of-type(" + parseInt(i+1) + ")").each(function(){
            //if a non-duplicate cell found, set flag to false
            if($(this).attr("data-duplicate")=="false"){
                isDuplicate=false;
            }
        });
        //if all cells in a column are duplicates, hide the column
        if(isDuplicate==true){
            $("#item-sizes-table td:nth-of-type(" + parseInt(i+1) + ")").hide();
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in one:

```
$("tr").find("td[data-duplicate=true]").not(":first").hide()
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rr4D6/7/

---

Here's a more sophisticated version, now I better understand the problem. This fiddle starts by showing the cells tagged as dupes in red, and adds a border to the table. Now it is a bit easier to see what columns we need to hide: all those where the entire column is red, apart from the first one.

Now click the button to do exactly that!

http://jsfiddle.net/Rr4D6/13/

```
hideDupeCols = function() {
    found_first = false
    var num_cols = $("tr").first().find("td").length, i
    for (i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
        var hide = true
        $("tr").each(function(j, tr) {
            hide = hide && $($(tr).find("td").get(i)).attr("data-duplicate") == "true"
        });
        if (hide) {
            if (found_first) $("tr td:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")").hide()
            else found_first = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that hides single cells, I need to compare if all data-duplicate = true for whole column not single cell.

Comment: gotcha. That might be a bit hard for a one-liner :-) ... let's see what can be done!